# Firebase User Chat Rating - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

First of all, I'm a real beginner in Android and want to learn.
I want to rate a user who responded to my initiated message using firebase. So only once can the user who initiated the conversation

rate the other user, but only after the response ( first response, no matter what response, even if it is just "hi")
He can receive any amount of ratings (positive or negative) but from different users), in my case, I add/subtract 10 for every vote.

My Firebase DB structure looks like this:

[image: firebase structure]

[image: firebase chat conversations]

Layout:

[image: layout]

- I have tried this way, but haven't succeeded:

  ```
  if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {

      messageRef = mRootRef.child("messages")
              .child(mCurrentUserId)
              .child(mChatUser);

      chatRef = mRootRef.child("chat")
              .child(mCurrentUserId)
              .child(mChatUser);

      final Query convQuery = chatRef;

      convQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Conv conversation = dataSnapshot.getValue(Conv.class);
              convVoted = conversation.isVoted();
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });

      Query messageCheckQuery = messageRef.orderByKey();

      messageCheckQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

              Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
              final String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
              String messageTo = message.getTo();
              voteBoolean = message.isVoted();

             if (!messageTo.equals(mCurrentUserId)) {

                  ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              } else {

                  if (!convVoted) {

                      ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                      Query query = mRootRef.child("user_account_settings")
                              .orderByKey()
                              .equalTo(mChatUser);

                      query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                              DataSnapshot singleSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
                              UserInfo userInfo = singleSnapshot.getValue(UserInfo.class);
                              voteNumberStr = userInfo.getMessage_rating();
                              Log.d("RATING", " Voted : " + convVoted + " | Rating Number :  " + voteNumberStr);
                          }

                          @Override
                          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                          }
                      });



                      mVoteUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View view) {

                              voteNumber = Integer.parseInt(voteNumberStr);
                              voteNumber = voteNumber + 10;
                              voteNumberStr = String.valueOf(voteNumber);
                              convVoted = true;
                              //voteBoolean = true;


                              mRootRef.child("messages")
                                      .child(mCurrentUserId)
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child(messageKey)
                                      .child("voted").setValue(true);

                              mRootRef.child("chat")
                                      .child(mCurrentUserId)
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child("voted").setValue(true);

                              mRootRef.child("user_account_settings")
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child("message_rating").setValue(voteNumberStr);
                              Log.d("RATING", " clicked : " + convVoted + " | Rating Number :  " + voteNumberStr);
                              ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                          }
                      });


                      mVoteDownBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View view) {

                              voteNumber = voteNumber - 10;
                              voteNumberStr = String.valueOf(voteNumber);
                              //voteBoolean = true;
                              convVoted = true;


                              mRootRef.child("messages")
                                      .child(mCurrentUserId)
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child(messageKey)
                                      .child("voted").setValue(true);

                              mRootRef.child("chat")
                                      .child(mCurrentUserId)
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child("voted").setValue(true);

                              mRootRef.child("user_account_settings")
                                      .child(mChatUser)
                                      .child("message_rating").setValue(voteNumberStr);
                              Log.d("RATING", " clicked : " + convVoted + " | Rating Number :  " + voteNumberStr);
                              ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          }
                      });

                  } else

                      {

                          ratingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                      }
              }

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });

  }
  ```

ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: so what is your actual problem? Seeking for idea on the implementation of rating, your code doesn't work or..?

Comment: it  doesn't work the way I have described. Yes, an advice of implementation would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Johannes. The question as it stands now is a bit broad. What happens when you run the code in a debugger? Which specific statement doesn't do what you expect it to do? I recommend checking out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since that shows how to maximize your changes of getting help quickly on code-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem i do this way, i perform the rating only on message click, i think is the best way.
remove the bottom rate.

[eg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfzpE.jpg)

Comment: I don't think I understood what you said. I do store the rate in users table (in my case: user_account_settings). and after every user that initiated the conversation rates the other user I am adding/subtracting the rate value. So the problem with rating count is not an issue, but how do I let only the user that initiated the conversation rate the other user, only after ( second user) he responded.

Comment: ( only the user who initiated the message has the rating layout active after response was received and until he votes)